# How to get a end string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some string which I already mentioned in previous question

```
s = "[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected"

s1="[1,12:12] call add() Asdfjgg Error Code: 1046. No database aa selected"

s2= "[1,12:12] call add()"

s3= "[1,12:12]"

s4="Error Code: 1046. No database selected"

s5="END: Error Code: 2134. database doen't exist"

regex=(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$))
```

using that regex I get output like

```
['1', '12:12', 'call basic_while1()']
['1', '12:12', 'call add() Asdfjgg']
['1', '12:12', 'call add()']
['1', '12:12']
['', '', '', 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
```

now I want to make change in that regex only and get out put like

```
['', '', '','Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
['', '', '','Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
['', '', '']
['', '']
['Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
```

I modified this to

```
(?:^\?:[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?$)?(Error Code:.*))|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$))
```

but it didn't work
is it possible to get output like this using that Regex?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried to get the output you want?

Comment: wait , let me add it into a question

Comment: You can't have newlines in string literals unless you use triple quotes.

Comment: got it, and  I recommend you to watch my last question @Barmar

Comment: Your question should be standalone. While linking toa previous question is fine as a reference, it should not be required to fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why does the expected result for the second string say `No database selected` instead of `No database aa selected`? Why is `aa` removed in the result?

Comment: Try `^(?:\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)](?:\s+(.*?)\s*)?|.*?)(Error Code:.*)?$`, see https://regex101.com/r/2sna1h/3 and https://ideone.com/m8Fq5b

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
regex='Error Code: \d+.*'
match = re.search(regex, s)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
    # Output:
    # 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected'
```

Comment: it works , but if scenario like s2 and s3 , it gives me a error , I want to make only one regex for it

Comment: @ThePjot  this sol is good , but I want to change in this  regex=(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$)) and want this kind of output .I don't want to make new regex , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^
(?:\[(?P<d1>[\d,]+):(?P<d2>[\d,]+)\]\ ?)?
(?:(?P<code>(?:(?!Error\ Code).)*))?
(?P<error>Error\ Code:.+)?
```

in verbose mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/phf9Pp/1/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
^                              # start of the line
(?:                            # non-capturing group
    \[                         # [
    (?P<d1>[\d,]+):            # digits and commas -> group "d1", followed by :
    (?P<d2>[\d,]+)             # group "d2
    \]\ ?                      # make the space optional
)?                             # make the whole group optional
(?:
    (?P<code>
        (?:(?!Error\ Code).)*) # everything until "Error Code"
     )?
(?P<error>Error\ Code:.+)?     # Error Code and anything that follows
```

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"""...above expression...""", re.M | re.X)
for m in rx.finditer(string):
    print(m.group('error')) # or any other group
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/fsE4wK) for the whole snippet.

Comment: this sol is good , but I want to change in this  regex=(?:^\[(\d+),(\s?[0-9:]+)\](?:\s+(.+?)\s?)?(?:Error Code:.*)?$)|(?:()()()(Error Code:.*$)) and want this kind of output .I don't want to make new regex , thanks